# c++, An array's values are unexpectedly changing somewhere, could you help me find out where?

Tags: c++, arrays, bmp

I am new to c++ and I am writing a program that writes BMP files. The information for every pixel of the file is stored in the array `Color *image;`
Color is a class that takes in three `int` values for rgb and assigns them to `unsigned char red`, `unsigned char green`, `unsigned char blue`.

I initialize `Color *image;` with:

```
    Color c(255,255,255);
    image = new Color[width*height];
    for(int row = 0; row < width; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < height; column++){
            image[column*width + row] = c;
            out << (int) image[column*width + row].red << " " << (int) image[column*width + row].green << " " << (int) image[column*width + row].blue << "\n";
        }
    }
```

`out` is an `ofstream` writing to a text file. It just confirms that it is writing the right values to that point of the array.

My problem arises when I use this code in another method:

```
for(int row = 0; row < width; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < height; column++){

            cout << (int) image[column*width + row].red << " " << (int) image[column*width + row].green << " " << (int) image[column*width + row].blue << "\n";

            out.write((char*) &image[column*width + row].red,1);
            out.write((char*) &image[column*width + row].green,1);
            out.write((char*) &image[column*width + row].blue,1);
        }
    }
```

It is trying to write the values of each part of `image` into a binary file. The `cout` yields random values, like "254 238 254". I close all of my streams and I don't use `image` anywhere else.

Where do my values change?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Confusing that your `row` variable iterates through columns and your `column` variable iterates through rows... I would expect to see `image[y * width + x]`, not the other way around.

Comment: Can you share how those two blocks of code go together? How are you passing `image` to the second method?

Comment: `image` is just declared as `Color* image;` in the header file, so I can directly access it from any method in the class.

Comment: Why are you casting the address of each color component to a `char*`?

Comment: The file I am writing to is binary, so I am casting `(char*)` to convert to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you got the error. Assuming the pointers you received are correct, why don't you just do the following, which is the standard way of dealing with binary files.

```
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(image), sizeof(Color) * width * height);
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me that! The values of `image` are still wrong though. Any ideas at all for why they would just change?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have any problem except that we often use "row" and "column" in the opposite way. I guess you need some interactive debugging to watch how the values change.